# PHP session destroyed / lost after header

Tags: php, session, header

I've got a script that sets some session values before redirecting to `/` using `header()`.

I've read many posts about the `$_SESSION` variable being destroyed / lost after `header()`, even after I implemented this:

```
// set session here

session_regenerate_id(true);
session_write_close();
header("Location: /");
```

`session_start()` is set in the correct places, does anyone know of anything that I might be missing?

On the index.php page I have this:

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);

// outputs nothing :'(
```

The code is pretty complex so will not post it all, just snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interest of closing this question, we had concluded it was a problem with the server configuration, not surprising considering the host is well known for this kind of thing.

Comment: Could you be more precise?

Comment: No, unfortunately I cannot. The host at the time didn't allow developers to modify the `php.ini` file, move to different host where we could control this and the problem was solved.

Comment: To any one reading this, I think I might have the solution. It is the accepted answer posted at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect

Answer (score 12):

I've never seen any session related issues due to using location headers - are you sure you're  calling [session_start](http://www.php.net/session_start) on both pages?

---

Hmm... this answer made a lot more sense before you added the session_start bits above, and mentioned the fact that you were sure you were using session_start. :-)

Comment: Even after removing the `session_regenerate_id` line the same problem persists.

Comment: And yes, I'm sure `session_start()` is being called in all the correct places.

Comment: If you take out the header location re-direct and simply change the URL (in the browser) is the session data available?

Comment: Hmmmm... it still isn't set, perhaps it's not a `header()` problem then?

Comment: I'd recommend using session_start as close to the start of any PHP includes as possible, and make the include the first item (i.e.: pre doctype/HTML headers, etc.) on all pages.

Comment: Straw clutching thought - I presume the disk area PHP is using for session data isn't full?

Comment: The server is reporting it has loads of space spare... shame I can't get SSH access to the box :-(

Comment: When I upload the same build to my web server the session works perfectly aft6er the header.

Comment: Sounds like a fun one. Incidentally, do *all* the partitions on the server have sufficient disk space? (Also, are quotas in use, etc.) Hope you manage to get it sorted anyhow. :-)

Comment: I only have access to the one partition... shared hosting blows. Any way thanks for your help... +1

Comment: Dear @JohnParker, after few days of "self-torture", thousands and after implementing thousands of different answers and tips on solutions I finally found out your answer. I never thought session_start() must be called on both pages.

Comment: ... as it's not the case for Java (I usually use Java). Thank you very very much!!!

Answer (score 5):

**header must be sent before session close**

```
session_regenerate_id(true);

header("Location: /");
// the header must be sent before session close
session_write_close(); // here you could also use exit();
```

Comment: I had the same problem and adding "exit()" after the redirect solved it

Answer (score 4):

just put exit; after header :D I solved by this

Answer (score 4):

After the Header redirect you need to exit the PHP script:

```
header("Location: /");
exit();
```

Comment: Since `exit` is a language construct you can just use `exit;` (no parentheses). Just e useful tip to save 2 characters of code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One possible option that was not mention here and happened to me is that I was creating another session. When you're using session in php you can use only one session at a time. If you create a new session the old one is lost. This is more likely to happen when you create a session for login and maybe you want another session for something else(It's not that recommended anyway). My case was a flash() method which I used to create a session only once a post was added/updated/deleted. And use that session in the views to display a message then destroy it. Every time I created a new session while adding/updating/deleting the other session that I used for login was destroyed. This is not something that happens to often but it's possible.

Comment: Review: I don't get it. I'm not native english, but your sentence confuses me. Would it require some text formatting with code blocks?

Comment: @H.Hasenack Yes I agree to you it was a short answer to understand anything from it. So I edited and expanded it. Hopefully now makes more sense.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I found that using a function related to Session helps to ensure if you started a session or not

```
if(session_status == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
   session_start();
```

Answer (score -4):

You don't need to start session_start() in each page. cuz untill your browser is closed the same session remains for the entire path you have specified in php.ini