# PHP: SESSION partly deleted after header() + exit

Tags: php, session, redirect, header

I am having some trouble with setting up a pretty small application. It's going to be a little survey.

The form is split into two pages. After submitting the first one, the data is stored in the `$_SESSION` array with this:

```
save_items(array('my_data' => $my_data_oject));
```

The function `save_items()` looks like this:

```
function save_items(array $array) {
    foreach ($array as $name => $item) {
        $_SESSION[$name] = $item;
    }
}
```

Then I `unset($_POST)`  and redirect like this:

```
header('Location: index.php?action=survey_part2');
exit;
```

My problem is: After redirection, the previously stored login data is still in the `$_SESSION`, but `my_data_object` is not. If I avoid the redirection, I can see that `my_data_object` is stored in the `$_SESSION` array before the redirection starts. So the combination of `header()` and `exit` seems to destroy the session in part. Does anybody know how this can happen?

Finally, parts of my controller:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

require_once 'models/functions.php';
require_once 'models/classes.php';

$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : NULL;
$view = $action;
$language = isset($_REQUEST['lang']) ? $_REQUEST['lang'] : 'de';

switch ($action) {
    case 'login' :
        if ((!empty($_POST['email'])) && (!empty($_POST['password']))) {
            $user = new User();
            $login = $user->find_user($_POST);
            if (!empty($login)) {
                set_message('Welcome ' . $login['Firstname'] . ' ' . $login['Lastname'] . '!');
                save_items(array('user_id' => $login['CID']));
                unset($_POST);
                redirect("index.php?action=survey&lang=de"); //<- works fine. Login is kept, Message is kept.
            } else {
                set_message('Please try again.');
                unset($_POST);
            }
        } else {
            unset($_POST);
            set_message('Try again.');
        }
    break;

/* ... shortage */
    case 'survey' :
        check_login(); //<- doesn't matter
        if (empty($_POST)) {
            /* ... shortage */
        } else {
            /* ... creation of my_data_object + setting one more message */
            save_items(array('my_data' => $my_data_object));
            unset($_POST);
            save_items(array('test' => 'you see me?')); //<- index.php?action=survey_2 won't get it
            //var_dump($_SESSION);
            header('Location: index.php?action=survey_2&lang=de'); //<- does not work. Login is kept in $_SESSION, but not my_data
            exit;
        }
    break;
```

Thanks!

This topic is maybe similar to [that one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037316/php-session-destroyed-lost-after-header),  but my `$_SESSION` is not empty after `header()`, but partly deleted.

Comment: its `header('Location: index.php?action=survey_part2');` and dont `unset($_POST);`

Comment: First point is true, I've corrected it. It was already OK  in my code. Using unset($_POST) or not does not hava any impact.

Comment: Is `session_start();` being called on your page `index.php?action=survey_part2` ?  Also, in the end of your "controller" you have `redirect('index.php?aktion=umfrage_2&lang=de');` - shouldn't that be `header('Location: index.php?action=survey_part2');`

Comment: 1.: Yes, it is. index.php is my Controller and remains the same, no matter which value 'action' has. 2. redirect() is indeed ambiguous, it is my own function for header('Location: index.php'); exit;. I'll edit that.

Comment: Maybe it is a cache related issue?

Answer (score 0):

Now I catched the problem. I tried to serialize a PDO with save_items() and after 1 day I've found the error message. My hint of the day: if you can, take a look into the php_error_log, because sometimes a very important error message is not shown on screen.

So my issue was relate to [that one!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700702/pdoexception-you-cannot-serialize-or-unserialize-pdo-instances)

Solution: Put data as an Array into $_SESSION or use __sleep() and __wakeup() to specify which attributes (not: $db = new PDO();) should be serialized and which not.