# Passing variables to next page through $_SESSION

Tags: php, variables, session

I need to pass a variable from **login.php** to **index.php** in order to get an error message if the user doesn't enter username or password. I have a modal form which pass `$_POST['usename']` and `$_POST['password']` to **login.php**.

**login.php**

```
require_once(realpath(__DIR__ . "/resources/session.php"));

if(!$logged) {
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

        if(strlen($_POST['username']) == 0 || strlen($_POST['password']) == 0) {
            $_SESSION['noty'] = "error||topCenter||(here the message)";
            header("Location: index.php");
        } else {
            // Code...
        }
    }
} else {
    // Code ...
}
```

`$_SESSION['noty']` is the variable that I should pass to **index.php**.

**index.php**

```
$page_id = 1;
require_once(realpath(__DIR__ . "/resources/session.php"));

require_once(TEMPLATE_PATH . "/header.php");
require_once(TEMPLATE_PATH . "/sidebar.php");
require_once(TEMPLATE_PATH . "/breadcrumb.php");

renderLayout(VIEWS_PATH . "/index.view.php");

require_once(TEMPLATE_PATH . "/footer.php");
```

and at the bottom of the **header.php** which is included on **index.php**:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['noty']) AND strlen($_SESSION['noty']) > 0) {
    $noty = explode("||", $_SESSION['noty']);
    noty($noty[2], $noty[1], $noty[0]);
    $_SESSION['noty'] = "";
} else {
    $_SESSION['noty'] = "";
}
```

Also `noty function` is:

```
function noty($text, $layout, $type) {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        noty({text: '$text', layout: '$layout', type: '$type'});
        </script>";
}
```

This isn't working. `$_SESSION['noty']` is **not** set when I get to **index.php** from **login.php**.

**EDIT 1:**

**session.php** contains `session_start()` on top and it is required on both **index.php** and **login.php**.

**EDIT 2:**

`exit;` after `header()` redirect doesn't works for me.

**SOLVED:**

I set `$_SESSION` to `array()` whenever a user wasn't logged in on **session.php**, so it was deleting also $_SESSION['noty']. That error was so stupid.

Comment: Did you call `session_start()` at the top of both pages?

Comment: `session_start`, do you use it?

Comment: Use `session_start()` to access the `$_SESSION` variables.

Comment: I do. session.php, which is required on both files, contains session_start() on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `header()` function, you shall use `exit;` function. More details: [PHP session destroyed / lost after header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037316/php-session-destroyed-lost-after-header)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work for me. `$_SESSION['noty']` is still unset on **index.php**.